# Error: Key Word Missing while inserting Multiple Columns into Table- Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I removed those quotes in middle for testing. But Still I am getting the same error. Could you please Look in to this.

```
insert all                          
  2  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Power Company',75,1)     
  3  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Record Club',25,2)
  4  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Software Company',250,1)
  5  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Cable TV company',35,3)                      
  6  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Joe car palace',350,5)                         
  7  select * from dual;
  2  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Power Company',75,1)
  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Full Length Query is below:

```
insert all                          
  2  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Power Company',75,1)     
  3  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Record Club',25,2)
  4  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Software Company',250,1)
  5  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Cable TV company',35,3)                      
  6  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Joe car palace',350,5)                         
  7  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('S.C.Student Loan',200,6)                              
  8  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Florida Water Company',20,1)
  9  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('U-O-Us Insurance Company',125,5)
 10  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Debtors Credit Card',35,4)           
 11  select * from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Could anyone please help me out in getting rid of this problem.

```
insert all
  2  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Phone Company',125,1)
  3  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Power Company',75,1)
  4  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Record Club',25,2)
  5  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Software Company',250,1)
  6  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Cable TV Company',35,3)
  7  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Joe''s Car Palace',350,5)
  8  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('S.C.Student Loan',200,6)
  9  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Florida Water Company',20,1)
 10  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('U-O-Us Insurance Company',125,5)
 11  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Debtor''s Credit Card',35,4)
 12  select * from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Comment: There is a black-blue-red tip in your post

Comment: The code you've just added doesn't match the error you've got...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 6, the string literal is being terminated early by the single quote in the value.

```
6  into bills(Name,Amount,Accoun_Id) values('Joe's car palace',350,5)
```

You can escape the single quote with another single quote: `Joe''s car palace`.  The same issue will also appear in line 10.

Comment: Hello Kevin, I tried removing those ambiguous quotes in the middle. But still geting the same error.

Comment: @user3749708 Post the full sql statement.

Comment: @user3749708 Do you include the line numbers in the actual sql?

Comment: Yes Kevin, While I am pressing enter for new entry, they came automatically.